# Breeze ignores resourcename when query by entity type name

Tags: odata, breeze, sharepoint-2013

I have a number of entity types that use the identical ResourceNames but are different in dataProperties fields and query *where* clause using 'ContentTypeId' (see code below).

In the last function listed (getCorrespondenceDocuments), if I use the entity type name 'Correspondence' in the *from* clause, Breeze ignores the defaultResourceName value provided and constructs the OData query using the entity type name as the resourcename string:

*/_api/**Correspondence**?$filter=ContentTypeId%20eq%20'0x01...22'&$select=Id%2CTitle%2CContentTypeId%2CCreated%2CModified%2CCorrespondenceType%2CCorrespondenceDate%2CCorrespondenceAuthor%2CCorrespondenceRecipient%2CCorrespondenceTopic%2CConfidentialFlag%2CFile&*

If I use the defaultResourceName in the *from* clause, Breeze will construct the OData request using the default document entity and the correct resourcename string but it does not include the correct dataProperties fields:

*/_api/**SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getByTitle('Documents')/items?@target='http://my.spserver.com/dev/JDP'&$expand=File**&$filter=ContentTypeId%20eq%20'0x01...22'&$select=Id%2CTitle%2CContentTypeId%2CCreated%2CModified%2CFile%2CConfidentialFlag&*

I also tried using the *.toType('Correspondence')* method to the last test. No fields are returned at all:

*/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getByTitle('Documents')/items?@target='http://my.spserver.com/dev/JDP'&$expand=File&$filter=ContentTypeId%20eq%20'0x01...22'&*

---

It appears that Breeze is assuming that your resource name will be different for each entity type.

How do I tell Breeze to use the correct entity data properties and resource name?

---

```
// Document type (default document type)
function addDocumentType() {
    addType({
          name: 'Document'
        , defaultResourceName: 'SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getByTitle(\'Documents\')/items?@target=\'' + spContext.hostWeb.url + '\'&$expand=File'
        , dataProperties: {
              Id: { type: breeze.DataType.Int32 }
            , Title: { nullable: true }
            , ContentTypeId: {}
            , Created: { type: breeze.DataType.DateTime }
            , Modified: { type: breeze.DataType.DateTime }
            , File: { complexType: 'Document:#File' }
            , ConfidentialFlag: { type: breeze.DataType.boolean, nullable: true }
        }
    });
}

// Correspondence type
function addCorrespondenceType() {
    addType({
          name: 'Correspondence'
        , defaultResourceName: 'SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getByTitle(\'Documents\')/items?@target=\'' + spContext.hostWeb.url + '\'&$expand=File'
        , dataProperties: {
              Id: { type: breeze.DataType.Int32 }
            , Title: { nullable: true }
            , ContentTypeId: {}
            , Created: { type: breeze.DataType.DateTime }
            , Modified: { type: breeze.DataType.DateTime }
            , CorrespondenceType: { nullable: true }
            , CorrespondenceDate: { type: breeze.DataType.DateTime, nullable: true }
            , CorrespondenceAuthor: { nullable: true }
            , CorrespondenceRecipient: { nullable: true }
            , CorrespondenceTopic: { nullable: true }
            , ConfidentialFlag: { type: breeze.DataType.boolean, nullable: true }
            , File: { complexType: 'Document:#File' }
        }
    });
}

function getDefaultDocuments(page) {
    return breeze.EntityQuery
    .from(documentType.defaultResourceName)
    .orderBy('Id')
    .skip(pageSize * (page - 1))
    .take(pageSize)
    .using(manager)
    .execute()
    .then(function (data) {
        return data.results;
    });
}

function getCorrespondenceDocuments() {
    return breeze.EntityQuery
    .from('Correspondence')
    //.from(correspondenceType.defaultResourceName)
    .where('ContentTypeId', 'eq', breeze.config.contentTypeIds.correspondence)
    .using(manager)
    .execute()
    .then(function (data) {
        return data.results;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Breeze generally assumes that a given endpoint returns the same type every time. I'm a little surprised that appending `.toType` to the query before executing it didn't work for you. Maybe I shouldn't be surprised; it has been a while since I was last in this part of the code base.

I think I'd begin diagnosing the situation by debugging through the `JsonResultsAdapter.visitNode` method, paying close attention to the `updateEntityNode` helper function. Somehow it is getting confused while determining the value of `result.entityType`, even when you append `.toType`.

If you have to fix the type determination here in `JsonResultsAdapter.visitNode, you should be looking for a way to disambiguate based on node and context. One obvious (perhaps hacky) way is to look for the existence of a`node.CorrespondenceType` property.

You might do that *after* you're sure that the query targeted this ambiguous endpoint. The `mappingContext` parameter to the `visitNode` method can tell you which endpoint you queried; see `mappingContext.query.resourceName`.

You have complete access to the query here so maybe there's another "telltale" that can help. For example, when you add the `.toType('foo')` clause to the query before executing it, the `mappingContext.query.resultEntityType` is the name of the type you specified (e.g., 'foo'). That's a darn good clue, don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *MetadataStore.setEntityTypeForResourceName* method:

http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/MetadataStore.html#method_setEntityTypeForResourceName

Also see the "EntityType/ResourceName map" section under http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/querying-locally

Comment: The *MetadataStore.setEntityTypeForResourceName* is the opposite of what I need.  

From the doc page: "This method is only needed in those cases where multiple resources return the same entityType."

I need multiple entityTypes from a single resource.